# Ping from VM - Check MK

Tags: azure, ubuntu, check-mk

I would like to install check MK Monitoring Server on an Ubuntu VM in Azure.
The query of the services to external works, however, not the ping.
(Ubuntu 14.04. LTS)

Which port or setting do I need to set in Azure?

```
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C
--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
99 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 98057ms
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the present Network Security Group design - you would need to open all the ports to the VM to allow for pings. [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9bb896d2-7b6c-4c2f-9f11-3147aa5ff528/azure-network-security-groups-allow-ping?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork). There's no way to allow for ICMP only currently.

Comment: Although the VM already was accessible with the IP, I had still activate a fixed IP.

Comment: @mgtz glad you sorted it out, if the answer helped you you should mark it as an answer :)